# How to convert eclipse java projects into groovy projects?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have set of ten to twelve native java projects checked out from svn. Eventually I am considering to convert all the code into groovy. I am only concentrating on these two steps first:

1) Convert java projects to Groovy projects

2) Change the extensions of all the 10,000 odd files in all the projects to .groovy.

So I want to know if eclipse can provide me some help with these two steps (via UI) without me having to change all the .classpath entries or .project entries.

PS: I already have the groovy plugin installed

Comment: You're going to have some problems however, as only about 99% of java code is actually correct Groovy code.  Static initializers are a big issue when converting, e.g.  int [] intarray = {1,2,3,4};

Comment: That's only 1 of the possible issues... you should look at the potential for hidden errors too.   Newlines inside non-parenthetical arithmetic can be a very subtle bug as well.  int x = 5 (newline) + 6; (newline) is actually TWO groovy statements.  One sets x to 5, and the other just results in 6.

Comment: I love groovy but I'm not sure this is a great idea--you are letting yourself in for a LOT of potential bugs with almost no gain since groovy and Java classes will live together just fine. Why not convert the files over one at a time when you need to just by renaming the file? Personally I'd prefer the core of my work remain in Java anyway, Java has less syntax than groovy and is therefore easier to use as a communication medium with other devs (which is the most important use of Code, the fact that it makes your comptuer do something is generally less important in the long run)

Answer (score 1):

Are the java projects also Maven projects?  That creates a bit more confusion, but is workable.  You should be able start by editing the .classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_SUPPORT"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/someDirectory"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

This is for a Maven and Groovy project.  You can leave out the Maven line if it is not needed.  Eclipse doesn't seem to like Maven+Groovy projects, so you will have to fix the .classpath again after you import it, but it won't change it again after that.

I'd recommend using a batch file for the renames (or a C# program, if you have VS installed, too).

I found this example:  https://superuser.com/questions/205083/which-command-can-i-use-to-recursively-rename-or-move-a-file-in-windows

For loops are a bit odd in batch files, but they work nicely.

I think that would get you going.  Start with the smallest project, of course!